# Compute value of nVarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a `table` named `transactions`, in that there is a `column` namely `rate` datatype `nvarchar`.
The value of the `column`, `rate`, is something like `1/2250`.

I am looking for a query whereby if I run that query, I should get the answer `0.0004`.

Something like below

```
Select cast(rate as int) as rate from transactions
```

The output I'm looking for is `0.0004` but now I am getting `invalid conversion from nvarchar to int`

Thanks.

Comment: `CAST()` does not evaluate the expression. It just convert from one data type (string) to another (int)

Comment: Also, `integer` isn't floating point number!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create table #tmpTable (rate varchar(10))
insert into #tmpTable values
('1'),('1/2250'),('1.04'),('1/4')

select case CHARINDEX('/', rate)
       when 0 then cast(rate as real) --if there's no division sign, then take number as it is
       else cast(SUBSTRING(rate, 1, CHARINDEX('/', rate) - 1) as real) / 
            cast(SUBSTRING(rate, CHARINDEX('/', rate) + 1,LEN(rate)) as real)
       end
from #tmpTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the Erro because there are non-numeric values in your column. Also Since you want the result with decimal parts, casting as INT won't work for you.

Try this

```
Select 
cast(rate as DECIMAL(10,4)) as rate 
from transactions WHERE ISNUMERIC(rate )=1
```

or

```
    Select 
cast(
    (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(rate )=1 
            THEN rate 
        ELSE 0 END
    ) as DECIMAL(10,4)) as rate 
from transactions
```

Comment: The point is, that the the `rate` is given as a string like `"1/2250"` This string must be computed first to get the needed value `0.0004` - not a simple `CAST`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are going is wrong but, you should do something dynamic approach

```
declare @data nvarchar(25) = '1/2250', @q varchar(50)

set @q = 'select '+@data+''

exec (@q)
```

**EDIT :** You could also try via some function approach and assumes you have other rates in format like `1/2250`

```
select cast(cast(left(rates, charindex('/', rates)-1) as decimal(10,4)) / 
       cast(reverse(left(reverse(rates), charindex('/', reverse(rates))-1)) as decimal(10,4)) as decimal(10,4)) rate
from table
```

Comment: OP's data is living in a table... This approach works, but is not very useful with a set based approach. Nor will it be useable in a function or VIEW

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @transaction TABLE(rate NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @transaction VALUES('1/5'),('1/2250'),('7/16');

SELECT t.rate
      ,CAST(A.Casted.value('/x[1]','decimal(10,4)') / A.Casted.value('/x[2]','decimal(10,4)') AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS ComputedRate
FROM @transaction AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.rate,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS A(Casted);
```

The result

```
rate    ComputedRate
1/5     0.2000
1/2250  0.0004
7/16    0.4375
```

Some explanantion:

TSQL does not allow dynamic evaluation of computable expressions...

There are possibilities with string literals or with dynamic SQL.
The first does not allow for dynamic values, the second is very limited: not inlined, no usage in views or functions etc.

This query will use a trick to split the value `1/2250` into `<x>1</x><x>2250</x>`. This allows to cast the expression to XML and query the first occurance and the second occurance of `<x>` separately. This is used for the computation.